# Why keys function does return key in random order in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dict1={'s':1,'a':2}
dict1.keys()
```

once time {'a','s'} and other time {'s','a'}
Why ?

```
   set1={'a','b'}
    set2={'b','c'}
    print(set1 | set2)
```

once time {'a','b','c'}, second time: {'c','b','a'} and etc.
Why ?
How can I print in deterministic order ?

Comment: `dict`s and `set`s are _**un-ordered**_ data structures. They have a random order when created, and it changes as the dictionary is operated upon.

Comment: 'No order' is more accurate than 'random order'. You can sort the keys by some criteria though. Look up something like 'how to sort dictionary keys python'.

Comment: Because the keys order in a dictionary is established based on the keys hashes that are computed on keys. The hash func is internal and subject to change between _Python_ releases.

Answer (score 0):

please `sorted` dict key for deterministic order.

```
dict1={'s':1,'a':2}
print(sorted(dict1.keys()))
```

Comment: `sorted(dict1)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is not guaranteed to have ordered keys.
If you need to retrieve keys in specific order, use `OrderedDict` from collections.

```
>>> b = OrderedDict([('k1','v1'),('k2','v2')])
>>> b.keys()
['k1', 'k2']
```